# VBA formula to calculate Age from Born Date

Tags: excel, vba

I have Born Dates and want apply this formula

```
=(YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(A2))
```

in VBA for calculate age for whole row of dates

for example

```
      A           B
1  BornDate      Age
2  09.06.1991    28
3  02.07.1973
4
5
```

my code works only for first two and stop without any error.

```
Sub btn_GetAge()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("B2:B" & LastRow) = "=(YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(A1))"
    End With

End Sub
```

Any idea or choose different formula ?

Comment: You should probably precise the column here: `.Cells(.Rows.Count,1)` If you dont, you wil get cell from left to right, then up to down. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.item

Comment: So, when a person in born on December 31 of the year 2018, at new year's day 2019, although only being one day old, your formula will say he's already a year old. Are you really sure about your formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close:

```
Sub btn_GetAge()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B2:B" & LastRow) = "=YEAR(TODAY())-YEAR(A2)"
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `Rows.Count` is missing the dot for the `With` statement. While in most cases this is not a problem, this code will fail in the case of `ActiveSheet` beeing a sheet that is not a worksheet (eg a chart sheet) in the moment this code runs. This was driving me nuts once.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ  **Thank you very much for your comment.** I had not considered the `Activesheet` being a *Chart*

Comment: Year is not enough if person is born end of year and you are days before isn't it ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/access/concepts/date-time/calculate-age

Answer (score 4):

1) Cells requires a row and column, e.g. A1 is Cells(1,1)

2) Your formula (and better to specify the property) starts in row 2 but refers to A1

```
Sub btn_GetAge()

Dim LastRow As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Formula = "=(YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(A2))"
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim CurrenctYear As Long, LoopYear As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            CurrenctYear = Year(Now)

        For i = 1 To Lastrow
            LoopYear = Year(.Range("A" & i).Value)
            .Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 1).Value = CurrenctYear - LoopYear
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```